# Creating a multi-branch tree in C

Tags: c, tree, addition, procedure

I'm new in C and I need to create a N-branch tree, but I can't get a grip on how C works.

So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    char type[50]; // There are two kinds of files: directory and archive
    int number_archives;
    struct nodo *next;
    struct nodo *son;
}NODE;

void create_Archive (NODO *ptr,char name[50]){ // ptr points to the node where I'll add the son
    NODE new_Node = {name,"Archive",0,NULL,NULL};
    ptr->son = &new_Node;
}
```

When I try to compile I get these warnings

```
filetree.c:15:3: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
NODE new_node = {name,"Archive",0,NULL,NULL};

filetree.c:15:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_node.name[0]’) [enabled by default]
filetree.c:15:3: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
filetree.c:15:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘new_node.name[1]’) [enabled by default]
filetree.c:15:3: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

How do I make the procedure name the archive the same way it is given in arguments of the procedure?

Another error that I'm always encountering is that when I try to use the function `malloc`,
for example:

```
number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I get the warning:

```
filetree.c:18:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
   number = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
```

Comment: First get a new keyboard or learn to proofread.  Second, you need to learn the difference between a value and a pointer to a value, that is the source of all of your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in the function shown.  One largely artificial problem is that you've incompletely translated `nodo` to `node` (and `NODO` to `NODE`); that's easily fixed, and leaves you with:

```
void create_Archive(NODE *ptr, char name[50])
{
    NODE new_Node = { name, "Archive", 0, NULL, NULL };
    ptr->son = &new_Node;
}
```

Problem 1 is being vociferously reported by the compiler; you can't initialize an array like `new_Node.name` by copying a pointer like `name` to it.  You need to use `strcpy()` for that.

The second problem is that you create a local variable, then store a pointer to it in the `ptr->son`, but when the function exits, the pointer becomes invalid and the space used for `new_Node` will soon be used for other purposes.  This is simply undefined behaviour.

You do need to use dynamic memory allocation to resolve this.  Whenever you use `malloc()` or one of its relatives, you must include `<stdlib.h>` — that is a sine qua non.  That will resolve the other problem you're reporting.  Putting this together, you end up with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void create_Archive(NODE *ptr, char name[50])
{
    NODE *new_Node = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(*new_Node));
    if (new_Node != NULL)
    {
        *new_Node = (NODE){ "", "Archive", 0, NULL, NULL };
        strcpy(new_Node.name, name);
    }
    ptr->son = new_Node;
}
```

This uses a C99 'compound literal' (that's the `(NODE){ … }` notation).  If you don't want to use that, then you'll need to use something more like:

```
void create_Archive(NODE *ptr, char name[50])
{
    NODE *new_Node = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(*new_Node));
    if (new_Node != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(new_Node->name, name);
        strcpy(new_Node->type, "Archive");
        new_Node->number_archives = 0
        new_Node->next = NULL;
        new_Node->sone = NULL;
    }
    ptr->son = new_Node;
}
```

When using `malloc()` or related functions, it is important to check the returned value, and do not dereference the pointer if it is NULL.

I observe that the notation with underscore separating words and initial capitals on subsequent words is an unusual hybrid notation.  The names `createArchive` and `create_archive` are the normal conventions.  It does no harm except that it is not normally used.

There are those who will excoriate me (and you) for [casting the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) as shown.  Given that you are not reliably including `<stdlib.h>` in your code, you should heed those people until you compile your code with options such that the omission will prevent your code from compiling.  I can use it because I always compile with options such as:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c node.c
```

and if I omitted `<stdlib.h>`, there'd be a compilation error.  Until you can confidently say you always compile with equivalent options, you should not cast the result from `malloc()` — and maybe you won't bother to learn the old-style idiom that was necessary in the days before ANSI C (C89), or that is still necessary if your code is intended to be compilable by a C++ compiler.  Renaming the file to `node.cpp` and compiling with G++ produces no errors or warnings either:

```
g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c node.cpp
```

That would not compile if the cast were omitted.  However, I am making no pretense whatsoever that the code is *good* C++; it is not — it is just written in the common subset of C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

There is not equality in arrays eg

```
new_Node.name = name;
```

Use *strcpy*:

```
NODE *new_Node = malloc(sizeof(NODE)); //get memory for new node
strcpy(new_Node->value, value); //copy value to new_Node.value
strcpy(new_Node->type, "Archive"); //copy "Archive" to new_Node.type
new_Node->number_archives = 0;
new_Node->next = NULL;
new_Node->son = NULL;
```

Comment: Also check the return value from `malloc()` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    typedef struct node {
        char name[50];
        char type[50]; // There are two kinds of files: directory and archive
        int number_archives;
        struct node *next;
        struct node *son;

    }NODE;


void create_Archive (NODE *ptr,char name[50]){ // ptr points to the node where I'll add the son
    NODE* new_Node = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(new_Node->name, name);
    strcpy(new_Node->type, "Archive");
    new_Node->number_archives = 0;
    new_Node->next = new_Node->son = NULL;
    ptr->son = new_Node;

}
```

- I thought that "nodo" and "NODO" should be "node" and "NODE", respectively.
- You should include `<stdlib.h>` when you use the function `malloc()`
- The data of local variables won't be maintained after you leave the scope, so you shouldn't return pointers to local variables.

Comment: Also check the return value from `malloc()` before using it.

Answer (score -1):

> Another error that I'm always encountering is that when I try to use
>   the function `malloc()`, for example:
>
> ```
> number = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
> ```
>
> I get the warning:
>
> ```
> filetree.c:18:21: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
>    number = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
> ```

You should include `<stdlib.h>` when you use the function `malloc()`.

Comment: While the last comment is true, this is hardly a complete answer, is it?